# Injecting JavaScript into a Post with WP3.x

Tags: posts, javascript

I have a client who is trying to inject some JS directly into a post using the web interface. The script is stripped out on the live site.

I am unable to replicate this behavior on a local installation. The JS is added as expected.

The main difference between my installation and the client's is that my installation is a fresh WP3 installation, whereas the client's is WP3 upgraded from WP2.

Is this a configuration option or a legacy issue? Is there some other reason why this might be happening?

Rich

Comment: On further digging, script is striped out if the code is entered as an author but not as an administrator. Is there anyway to remove this restriction?

Comment: Does the client adds js in wysiwyg mode or html mode? And what about you? I think that in HTML only, js code isn't stripped.

Comment: @rilwis HTML mode. From my testing, it would appear that JS is striped out for Authors. Though I've found no documentation to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in my installation, Admin and Editors are able to inject script into their posts. Authors are not able to.

Author content is parsed using a plugin called KSES, which strips out disallowed HTML.

The KSES plugin can be overridden or extended. Which I have done by hacking a community plugin called Extend KSES (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extend-kses/).

Not too keen on the idea of allowing script injection, so the client should be made aware of the dangers.

Rich

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken about the issue - that is controlled by [`unfiltered_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html) capability. Only available to Editor role and higher by default.